# How to XML add attribute to same Element?

Tags: php, xml

I have this type of XML format:

```
<root>
    <NotOfferNameList>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
    </NotOfferNameList>
</root>
```

And I want to add dynamic attribute id to offerName Like:

```
<OfferNameList>
          <OfferName id="1">...</OfferName>
          <OfferName id="2">...</OfferName>
          <OfferName id="2">...</OfferName>
        </OfferNameList>
```

I'm using PHP `SimpleXMLElement` and using `OfferName->addAttribute('id', $i);`

But is adding only id for first OfferName and showing out like:

```
 <OfferNameList>
              <OfferName id="1">...</OfferName>
              <OfferName>...</OfferName>
              <OfferName>...</OfferName>
            </OfferNameList>
```

Can any one help me figure out this...?

Comment: edit your question and post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `for()` loop you can obtain your desired result:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );

$nodes = $xml->NotOfferNameList->OfferName;
for( $i = 0; $i < count($nodes); $i++ )
{
    $nodes[$i]->addAttribute( 'id', $i+1 );
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <NotOfferNameList>
      <OfferName id="1">...</OfferName>
      <OfferName id="2">...</OfferName>
      <OfferName id="3">...</OfferName>
    </NotOfferNameList>
</root>
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/545941)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks , really you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can use *index* to access second, third, so on.. child element of the same name :

```
//add attribute to the 2nd OfferName :
$OfferNameList->OfferName[1]->addAttribute('id', $i);

//add attribute to the 3rd OfferName :
$OfferNameList->OfferName[2]->addAttribute('id', $i);

....
```